# Typo3 Mount Point Link

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I am creating a Mountpoint subpage menü in Typoscript. As you can see in the picture "Max Tester 2" is the parent Element of the menu. So i create a subpages menu. All Sites under "Max Tester 2" will be shown in this menu. So i create a kind of listview. I am using mount points to show a image and a title in this menu from another page. This image and title is created via MASK extension in the pagesettings of the Linked mount page. Its already working! But my problem is I want to Link to the original page (where I define the image and the title) and not the the Mounted Page. Now when i klick on the Listview element "tester" i am navigating to the "tester" mount page (as you can see in the picture). But i want to navigate to the original page where i defined (title and image). Is this possible? so that i can use the content of a different page with mount point and also to change the link of the mounted page? so i need a mix of mount point and shortcut.

[mount point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLubY.png)

Comment: Out of curiosity; Why not add a link to the original page instead of the mount point (because you want to have a link to the original page)? This looks like a conceptual problem because when you actually want to link to a mount point, you wouldn't be able to do so if you would implement something to work around it.

Comment: I have to use a Mount Point so that i can use the Image and the Text from another page, defined in the site property of the mounted page..

Comment: Still sounds like the wrong concept to me (but I don't have the full picture). From what I know now, I'd say all the data belongs on the main page. The mount point is to "display that page as another page inside another part of the root line", which is what I'd avoid like using `!important` in CSS unless it is _really_ necessary, as it also created duplicates content. If you want to navigate to the "original" page, link the "original page"; If you want the same page content at another rootline part but _not_ navigate to the origin page, use a mount point. Crowbar'ing the system is never good.

Comment: first of all thanks for the feedback! ok i guess i didn't explain it well. So here again: I create blog posts under one page. these blog posts have a backend layout so that I can enter a photo + a title in the page properties using the MASK extension. now I would like to display this photo + title on another page (listview), for this I use a mount point. The problem is that it is displayed, but with a click on this post I will not link to the original page --> but to the mount page ...